# Вычислить высоту прыжка

Tags: физика

Приветствую господа знатоки!

К сожалению, мне (надеюсь только пока-что) не дает физика, я либо тупой, либо да.

Так вот, я не могу найти формулу для вычисления высоты прыжка (используется только координата Y), а из входных данных имеется только скорость, гравитация, и трение.

Может быть есть у кого-то ответ? :з

Comment: Этот вопрос не имеет ничего общего с Stack Overflow на русском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Квадрат скорости делится на `2` и на гравитацию.

```
h = V^2/2g
```

Никакого трения при вертикальном прыжке быть не может

Comment: *Никакого трения при вертикальном прыжке быть не может* - парашютисты вышли из чата.